# Termux find if microphone or camera is in use by other apps

Tags: camera, android-10, microphone, termux

I want to make a simple script in termux to find out if microphone or camera is in use by other apps.
You can suggest me any method , it dont have to be soley based on termux I just somehow want to get that info in termux script

Other details :--

Android version : 10

Root : no

ROM: stock miui(12)

Correct me if my question need more details

Comment: I don't think termux has any privileges to do that. you might however find some info in logcat (don't know what to look for)